# String bean в Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

Всем привет

не получается инициализировать мой стринг. Он должен инициализироваться в xml. этого почему то не происходит.

в классе

```
@Autowired
private String host;
```

в конфигурации

```
<bean id="host" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="${host}"/>
</bean>
```

${host} - должен тянуть данные из файла проперти.

класс где лежит переменная

```
package ru.kladr.rest;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/address_service")
public class RESTController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RESTController.class);
    @Autowired(required = false)
    KladrRepository kladrRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CacheRun cacheRun;
    private ObjectsForCoordinatersResponce objectsForCoordinatersResponce;
    private final String VALUEREQUESTMAPPINGRESTCONTROLLER = "/address_service";
    private final String VALUEREQUESTMAPPINGGET = "/yandex_html_map/{code}";
    @Autowired
    private String host;
    private String map_url = host + VALUEREQUESTMAPPINGRESTCONTROLLER + VALUEREQUESTMAPPINGGET;
    private SecondLvl secondLvl = null;
    private Utilproperties utilproperties = new Utilproperties();
...
}
```

описание в xml

```
<context:component-scan
            base-package="ru.kladr.rest"/>
<bean id="cacheRun" class="ru.kladr.cache.CacheRun">
        <property name="maxfirstLvl" value="${maxfirstLvl}"/>
        <property name="numberReq" value="${numberReq}"/>
        <property name="numberReqCallVoidRecache" 
value="${numberReqCallVoidRecache}"/>
        </bean>
<bean id="kladrRepository" class="ru.kladr.db.KladrRepository" init-method="postConstruct">
    </bean>
```

Comment: Если вместо `${host}` написать `Hello`, инициализация пройдёт?

Comment: cделал @Value(${host}), потом сделал @Resource тоже самое. Сделал в xml  <constructor-arg value="hello"/> все равно null

Comment: при этом я инициализирую конструкторы разных сущностей используя данные из пропертей и все ок проходит

Comment: Тогда придётся показать класс окружающий внедряемую строку и место и место, где он объявляется бином.

Comment: да сделал это, добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, в xml конфигурации не хватает импорта пропертей:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:common.properties" />
```

Это зарегистрирует BeanFactoryPostProcessor, который отвечает за парсинг плейсхолдеров и прочитает свойства из указанного файла. Если не поможет, то можно попробовать:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:common.properties")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

При этом static обязателен,т.к. без этого плейсхолдеры в конфигурациях (а это Ваш случай) заменяться не будут.

Answer (score 0):

сделал бином отдельный класс проперти и от него вытянул настройки

```
public class Utilproperties {
    private Properties prop;
    private URL url;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RESTController.class);

    public Utilproperties() {
        prop = new Properties();
        url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("common.properties");

        try {
            prop.load(url.openStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Сбой при загрузке настроек application.properties");
        }
        log.info(toString());
    }

    public Properties getProp() {
        return prop;
    }
}
```